# Calculation of a RG-transformed energy functional

Tags: energy, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Consider the Landau-Wilson energy functional in a constant magnetic field:

$$E[m] = \int d^dx \left[\frac{1}{2} \vec\partial m(x))^2+ \frac{1}{2} r_0 m^2(x) + u_0m^4(x) + hm(x)\right]$$

We will integrate over a small momentum shell characterized by $b = 1$, i.e. over the spherical shell of radius $\Lambda$ and thickness $\delta k = \tau * \Lambda$ , where $\tau = \ln (b)$. We expand the field as:

$$m(x) = \bar m (x) + \delta m(x) \ ; \ \ \  \delta m(x) = \sum_{i=0}^N c_i \phi_i (x) \ .$$

The $N$ wave packets $\phi_i(x)$ are of the spatial size $\delta x = 1/\delta k$  and they are localized in the momentum shell $\delta k$. They are orthonormal and they also satisfy:

$$\int d^dx (\phi_i(x))^{2n+1} = 0 \ .$$

The background $\bar m$ is assumed to be constant over the plain wave packets.

**My question is** : How do we show that the renormalization group(RG)-transformed energy functional (by integrating out the background at one-loop) is given by:

$$E'[\bar m] = E[\bar m] + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^N\log\left(1 +  \frac{r_0}{\Lambda^2} + \frac{12u_0}{\Lambda^2}\bar m^2(x_i)\right)$$

where $x_i$ is the center of the mass of the wave packet $i$ .